# angular-2 modal. Prevent close when clicking with mouse

Tags: angular

I'm using the above plugin in my Angular 5 app. I'm trying to prevent the default behaviour of the dialog closing when the user clicks anywhere with the mouse. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bsmodal, you can put [config]="{ backdrop: 'static' }" at modal div. Example:

```
<div class="modal fade" bsModal #configModal="bs-modal" [config]="{ backdrop: 'static' }" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="configModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
</div>
```

Comment: Thats great but unfortunately I'm using angular-2 modal